# How to retrieve JSON file data using ajax and when the user clicks on the button the content displays in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to generate a table dynamically and then sort the elements of that table in my webpage but from the JSON file I am not able to retrieve the data
on the click of the button to generate the table. Can I get to know where I am wrong with my code.

```js
// teamdetail.json file data:
{
  "teamList": [{
      "date": "24/07/2016",
      "venue": "Bengaluru",
      "matchdetails": "Qualifier 1 ? Gujarat Lions vs Royal Challengers Bangalore"
    }, {
      "date": "25/07/2016",
      "venue": "Delhi",
      "matchdetails": "Eliminator ? Sunrisers Hyderabad vs Kolkata Knight Riders"
    },
    {
      "date": "27/07/2016",
      "venue": "Bengaluru",
      "matchdetails": "Qualifier 2 ? Q1 Loser vs EL Winner"
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#getdetail").click(function() {
    $.getJSON('teamdetail.json', function(data) {
      var detail = '<tr><th colspan = 3>Playoff Team Schedule</th></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>Date</th><th>Venue</th><th>Match Details</th></tr>';
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        detail += '<tr>';
        detail += '<td>' + value.date + '</td>';
        detail += '<td>' + value.venue + '</td>';
        detail += '<td>' + value.matchdetails + '</td>';
        detail += '</tr>';
      });
      $('#teamdetail').append(detail);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="getdetail">Get Team Details</button>
<table id="teamdetail"></table>
```

Comment: can you check your console network panel , where is the file teamdetail.json located ?

Comment: @HasanAl-Natour, I have written the code for teamdetail.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because your JSON response is not an array - its an object with a property `teamList` which is the array you want to loop over.

If you replace `$.each(data, ...)` with `$.each(data.teamList, ...)` it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I understood your explaination.

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop over **data['teamList']**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#getdetail").click(function() {
    $.getJSON('teamdetail.json', function(data) {

      var detail = '<tr><th colspan = 3>Playoff Team Schedule</th></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>Date</th><th>Venue</th><th>Match Details</th></tr>';

      $.each(data['teamList'], function(key, value) {
        detail += '<tr>';
        detail += '<td>' + value.date + '</td>';
        detail += '<td>' + value.venue + '</td>';
        detail += '<td>' + value.matchdetails + '</td>';
        detail += '</tr>';
      });
      $('#teamdetail').append(detail);
    });
  });
});
```

I hope it should help you Cheers!